# Cannot add a new user after extending user model in django

Tags: python, django

I can't add a new user it just says that the foreign key constraint failed I don't know why. I don't know which foreign key is violated and why is it violated.
Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


def user_avatar_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/avatar/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)

class board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.name)

class User(AbstractUser):
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(
        board, through='board_member', related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class list(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    board = models.ForeignKey(
        board, related_name="lists", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class board_member(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="memberships", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    board = models.ForeignKey(
        board, related_name="memberships", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("%s is %s in board %s" % (self.user, self.access, self.board))


class card(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(list, related_name="cards",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    due = models.DateField()
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: As I mentioned on your other question, there is no reason to have a custom user model here. A many-to-many field works in both ways, so you can put the field on `board` and remove your User model. (Also, you should use PEP8 style for your classes: Board, BoardMember, List, etc.)

Comment: First try to change User model name to CustomUsers, secondly did you follow proper documentation for this purpose

Comment: Changing your user model is not a trivial process. If you really need/want to do it, there is some advice here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313